# Show plots inside module in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to show plots inside a module (maybe recursive):

```
m = Module[{i, j}, i = 3; Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 1}]; j = 4]
```

Even

```
m = Module[{i, j}, i = 3; Show[Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 1}]]; j = 4]
```

not work. Why is this, and how to plot correctly?

Comment: you have suppressed the output of `Plot` with the semicolon... try `m = Module[{i = 3, j = 4}, Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 1}]]`. If your `i` and `j` assignments depend on the specific location in the code block (i.e., if this is a simplified example), use `m = Module[{i, j, p}, i = 3; p = Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 1}]; j = 4; p]`

Comment: very similar question was just asked at Mathgroup "Plot in module" http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Dec/msg00605.html (may be we need a Mathematica FAQ ?, as I've seen this question asked many times before)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only reason a plot is normally displayed in Mathematica is that the `Plot` function *returns* the graphics object representing the plot, and Mathematica displays the return value of whatever you run in a notebook. However, when you follow the statement with a semicolon, you prevent it from returning a value.

What you can do if you need to display something from within the middle of a module is `Print[Plot[...]];`. The `Print` function displays the value of its argument directly.

Comment: I think that in this case the name of the command, `Show`, suggests that it is doing something other than what it does (`Show` merges the display off several `Graphics` objects, it does not cause them to be shown)